# Passing Arguments to Method registered with onAction Event(VBA - Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

How do you pass an argument to a method which is registered with the onAction event in Excel VBA?

The code I have is:

```
With ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(rCell.Left, rCell.Top, rCell.Width, rCell.Height)
        .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        .Caption = ""
        .OnAction = "CheckboxChange"
End With
```

I want to pass the "rCell" to the "CheckboxChange" sub routine. Any way to do that. Basically I want to know the cell in which the checkbox was present in the CheckboxChange sub routine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel, VBA: How to pass multiple variables to .OnAction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079727/excel-vba-how-to-pass-multiple-variables-to-onaction)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this:

```
.OnAction = "CheckboxChange"
```

To this:

```
.OnAction = "'CheckboxChange""" & rCell & """'"
```

""" = 3 double quotes

"""'" = 3 double quotes & 1 single quote & 1 double quote

Comment: I recommend using chr(34) for " to avoid this sort of confusing multiple " situation

Answer (score 3):

with chr(34) instead of quote ("), it might be easier,

I have an example with 3 string arguments:

```
.OnAction =  "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!'Importer_Items_Temp_par_Menu_Déroulant " & Chr(34) & Nom_Fichier & Chr(34) & " , " & Chr(34) & Old_Val & Chr(34) & " , " & Chr(34) & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Import_Objets").Cells(Item_Num, q * 2).Value & Chr(34) & "'"
```

.

Where Importer_Items_Temp_par_Menu_Déroulant is a macro,

Nom_Fichier is a string variable,

Old_Val too,

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Import_Objets").Cells(Item_Num, q * 2).Value is a string too, from a cell in a sheet.

Answer (score 1):

The `Excel.Checkbox` control has the property `LinkedCell`. Set this property to the value of `rCell.Address` or the like. Set `OnAction` to the `CheckboxChange` macro. To get the clicked checkbox, use `Evaluate(Application.Caller)` inside of `CheckboxChange`. `Application.Caller` will be the checkbox's name, and `Evaluate` returns the checkbox object itself. Using this object you can get its `Name` or `LinkedCell`.