# Excel, VBA: How to pass multiple variables to .OnAction

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to pass multiple variables to a .OnAction call for a button.  I have not been able to find answers that relate to multiple variables, and I can do it with just one variable.  Here is what I have that works for one variable:

```
shpBar.OnAction = "'Button_Click """ & strText & """'"
```

How can I add two other variables to this (such as VarA and VarB)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming that VarA and VarB are variants or numeric variables, this would work:

```
.OnAction = "'Button_Click """ & strText & """," & varA & "," & varB & " '"
```

If they are strings, you need to add two more double-quotes around each variable name.

```
.OnAction = "'Button_Click """ & strText & """,""" & varA & """,""" & varB & """ '"
```

Comment: When I run your example, I get an "Object required" error message.  Do you know if I am missing something else?  I have the "Button_Click" method taking in the correct parameters, and I have tried both variations that you provided.  Can you think of why I might be getting this error?  Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm not sure.  It would be helpful to see more code.  What types of variables are "varA" and "varB"?  It did work with just the one variable as you showed in your original question, right?

Comment: Ok.  I'm still curious about the variable types.  Also, what's the line of code highlighted?

Comment: The highlighted code is the .OnAction line that I have been trying to pass the 3 variables

Comment: Here is what I am trying to pass (and of course all variables have been set):

Dim strText as String
Dim lngNumber as Long
Dim dtDate as Date

.OnAction = "'Button_Click """ & strText & """," & lngNumber"," & dtDate & " '"

Sub Button_Click(name As String, number as Long, startDate As Date)

MsgBox name " - " & number & " - " & startDate

end sub

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out how to add code "correctly" in comments!

Comment: You need an ampersand between name and "-".  Also, "name" is a reserved VBA word.  Best practice would be change it to something else.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I was unaware of that.

Comment: After trying it out, it worked perfectly!  Thanks so much for your help!  I really appreciate it!

Comment: To me this looks like an incredibly complicated mode of passing around parameters. Every time I jump in this it needs hours of testing. Having a single argument is simple, two is hell, three is mental devastation.