# Passing variables when calling a sub from .OnAction (custom right click menu)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a custom right click menu. Here is part of the code. It works well:

```
With menu.Controls.Add(Temporary:=True, Type:=msoControlButton, before:=i_menu)
    .BeginGroup = False
    .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "'complet """ & num_doc & """'"
    .FaceId = 1087
    .Caption = "Complété"
    .Tag = "commande_custom"
End With
```

As you can see, on action, it calls the sub complet(num_doc as String). I modified the sub so it would recieve another string: complet(num_doc as String, etape_doc as String). I can't for the life of me figure out the proper amount of " I need to put in there! Can someone explain how these quotations work? Something like:

```
.OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "'complet """ & num_doc & num_etape"""'"
```

PLEASE tell me if I can call it in a simpler way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not tested:

```
.OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "'complet """ & num_doc & """,""" & num_etape & """'"
```

source -> [Excel, VBA: How to pass multiple variables to .OnAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079727/excel-vba-how-to-pass-multiple-variables-to-onaction)

Comment: Tried and tested, works well. Thank you! I'd vote up if it weren't for my 13 reputation (heh).