# Use comma separated string as function parameters

Tags: string, excel, vba, function, parameters

I have created a comma separated string. I want to use this string as input in an Application.Run procedure.

The string looks exactly like below - with quotes..

```
MyString = "First_Number", "Second_Number", "Third_Number"
```

I want to use this string as parameter input:

```
Application.Run("'" & "Book2.xlsm" & "'!MySub", *MyString*)
```

It doesn't work.. I get an "argument not optimal".

I build the string with the following code, and the range is just a row with the parameters.

```
Function csvRange(myRange As Range)

Dim csvRangeOutput

For Each entry In myRange
    csvRangeOutput = csvRangeOutput & entry.Value & """, " & """"
Next
csvRange = Left(csvRangeOutput, Len(csvRangeOutput) - 4)

End Function
```

Hope someone can help.

Comment: I don't really have time to answer fully but take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30536949/custom-menu-passing-a-worksheet-variable-through-onaction VBA is ridiculous with quotation counts, so make sure to debug.print and check that each type of variable has the appropriate number of quotations around it.

Comment: Just pass in a single string like `MyString = "first_number,second_number,third_number"` then in `MySub`  use `Split` to separate it into the individual arguments and use as required?

Comment: Where are you getting the values for `MyString` from? Do they vary in number? What about a ParamArray?

Comment: Hi Brian, I am keeping the values in a table. So in column A I have the name of the function I want to call and then the subsequent columns contains the parameters. I hope this will allow me to run numerous functions in the same subs with varying number of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Evaluate might do the trick. Look at this piece of test-code:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim params As String
    params = "3,5"
    Debug.Print Evaluate("addNumbers(" & params & ")")
End Sub

Function addNumbers(a As Integer, b As Integer) As Integer
    addNumbers = a + b
End Function
```

It's code that writes code, how exiting! :D

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use something like this.

```
String MyString = "First_Number, Second_Number, Third_Number";
String words[] = MyString.split(",");
```

Then use the individual words as words[0],words[1], etc.

or you can loop through the array words[] and use the individual terms as you like.