# Pass multiple variables to .OnAction with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add `.onAction` with three variables to a button on an Excel sheet.

I followed
[Excel, VBA: How to pass multiple variables to .OnAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079727/excel-vba-how-to-pass-multiple-variables-to-onaction) to pass multiple variables.

When I click the button, it is throwing an error

> "Cannot Run the Macro "Deck v.1'!'Stop_SAP "10.x.x.x", sidadm, " ". The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros has been disabled.

If I don't pass any variables it is working.

.OnAction = "Stop_SAP"

```vb
With btn1
    .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Size = 8
    .TextFrame.Characters.Caption = "Stop SAP"
    .OnAction = "'Stop_SAP """ & hstname & """ ,""" & usrname & """,""" & pass & """'"
    .Line.visible = False
End With
```

Comment: Is the procedure you are calling in a regular module? - Or did you put it into a WB/WS-module. If so put it into a regular module

Answer (score 1):

The problem was with existing shapes. Just delete all shapes on the exit using

```
Dim Shp As Shape

For Each Shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
 Shp.Delete
Next Shp
```