# Dynamically added button, how to get some sort of value in the function

Tags: excel, vba

I dynamically add a button to each row I create in a table. Each button has a unique name and calls the same function BtnGoogle. This function should return a value in the same row as the button was placed in. Since the buttons are not actually part of the row, I need some way to transport the row number to the function, but I'm running out of ideas:

```
    Set btn = sheet.Buttons.Add(targetCell.Left, targetCell.Top, targetCell.Width, targetCell.RowHeight)
    With btn
      .OnAction = "BtnGoogle"
      .Caption = "Google Tag"
      .Name = "Btn" & CStr(lastRow(columns("Button1").Index).Address)
    End With

Sub BtnGoogle()
    MsgBox Application.Caller
End Sub
```

I'm able to show the button name in the messagebox this way, but I can't do anything with that Caller and get the row number I passed in from the string. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use the targetCell to get the current number like targetCell.Row will return the row number of a cell.

Comment: Does the button have a Tag property you could store the row number in - using the targetCell as @Sudharsan mentioned.  You haven't provided enough code to test easily.

Comment: Following Sudharsan's comment showing how to get the Row, you can pass the Row number as an argument into the BtnGoogle Sub using this method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410115/passing-arguments-to-method-registered-with-onaction-eventvba-excel

Comment: `Activesheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).Topleftcell` will give you a reference to the cell under the top left corner of the button you clicked.

Comment: Is targetCell an attribute of a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub BtnGoogle()

    Dim addr As String

    addr = Replace(Application.Caller,"Btn","")

    MsgBox ActiveSheet.Range(addr).Value ' for example

End Sub
```